# Toggle method not working properly in Android Studio using JAVA

Tags: java, android

I made simple dark/light mode switcher. The application `OnCreate` detects the mode you are on and than changes the boolean. I'm toggling this boolean and theme with button but for some reason it changes to false after second click. It only does that when the boolean is true. On false it works fine. Here's my code:

```
ImageButton dark_light;
boolean isDarkMode;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dark_light = findViewById(R.id.dark_light);

    int nightModeFlags =
            getApplicationContext().getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode &
                    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
    switch (nightModeFlags) {
        case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
            dark_light.setImageResource(R.drawable.light);
            isDarkMode = true;
            break;

        case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
            dark_light.setImageResource(R.drawable.dark);
            isDarkMode = false;
            break;
    }


    dark_light.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!isDarkMode) {
                dark_light.setImageResource(R.drawable.light);
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                isDarkMode = true;
            } else {
                dark_light.setImageResource(R.drawable.dark);
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                isDarkMode = false;
            }
            Log.d("Dark_Light", String.valueOf(isDarkMode));
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: If it changes on every clicks then it means it is working. What's the problem?

Comment: It's not changing when it's true. I have to click it twice in order to switch it to false again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever night mode is toggled, `onCreate` will be called again.

`getApplicationContext().getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;`  always gives you the initial configuration so you are always writing the same value to `isDarkMode` whenever the night mode is toggled.

To get the current night mode configuration, use `AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode()` instead

```
    int nightModeFlags = AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode();
    switch (nightModeFlags) {
        case AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES:
            dark_light.setImageResource(R.drawable.light);
            isDarkMode = true;
            break;

        case AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO:
            dark_light.setImageResource(R.drawable.dark);
            isDarkMode = false;
            break;
    }
```